SwiftUI Toggle - Handling mixed state
I am trying to get a mixed state Toggle switch working with a property in my Model. To enable mixed state you need to pass the Toggle an array of structs containing bools. If the bools are different the mixed state is shown. Since I need to do something else after the Toggle is flipped I am using a Binding { get set } on the Toggle:
struct IsOn: Equatable{
    var isOn: Bool
}

@Observable
class Model{
    var myBool = [IsOn(isOn: true), IsOn(isOn: false)]

    func boolValue()->[IsOn]{
        print("Calling")
        return myBool
    }

    func setBoolValue(value: [IsOn]){
        print(value[0].isOn)
        myBool = value
        dump(myBool)
    }
}

struct MyView: View{
    @Environment(Model.self) var model
    
    var body: some View{
        Toggle("Test", sources:  Binding<[IsOn]>(
            get: { model.boolValue() },
            set: { value in
                if value[0] == value[1]{
                    print("Update")
                    model.setBoolValue(value: value)
                }
            }), isOn: \.isOn)
    }
}


This works - up to a point. When first running, the Toggle does show the mixed value and clicking on the Toggle sets it to true and MyModel.setBoolValue gets called once, but the Toggle refuses to go back to false on another click. The other weirdness is that “Calling” in the getter gets called up to a dozen times.
Also I need to check if value[0] is the same as value[1] in the Toggle setter because Toggle.set gets called called multiple times - once for each item in the array as it gets changed from true to false or vice versa, so I wait until they are all the same before updating the model. My real model can have many values - so this is a bit of an issue as well.
Can anyone see why the Toggle might refuse to flip back to false on the second click? Or a better way to handle a mixed state? The way Toggle works for mixed state seems fine in simple examples but unnecessarily complicated in the real world, unless I’m completely missing something.

Your question of what you want to achieve is not clear to me. What is a mixed state Toggle switch?
Can you explain a bit more what exactly you want to achieve?

The SwiftUI Toggle is a checkbox. Checkboxes can have 3 states, on, off or mixed ( a dash - ). When a checkbox in a mixed state is clicked it becomes on and another click will set it to off. You can only really go back to the mixed state externally. Say you have a selection, of which only some of the items are locked - you want to show a mixed state for the locked toggle in a 'properties' view. Clicking on the toggle will set the selected items to 'locked' etc. Hope that helps.

See Checkbox with a third option: "partial", displayed as a dash in a box

If you want to have 3 states, then create a model that can cater for 3 states.
Here is some example code that lets you do what you describe
When a checkbox in a mixed state is clicked it becomes on and another click will set it to off. You can only really go back to the mixed state externally.
Note a Toggle can only display a on or off representation,
there is no undetermine display possible.
Example code:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        MyView()
            .environment(model)
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @Environment(Model.self) private var model

    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var model = model
        VStack (spacing: 33) {
            ForEach($model.modelStates) { $mx in
                HStack {
                    Text(mx.state.rawValue)
                    Button("Ckeck me") {
                        switch mx.state {
                        case .isOn: mx.state = .isOff
                        case .isOff: mx.state = .isOn
                        case .isUnknown: mx.state = .isOn
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Button("Uncheck [0]") {
                model.modelStates[0].state = .isUnknown
            }
        }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
    }
}

@Observable class Model {
    var modelStates = [MixState(state: .isOn), MixState(state: .isUnknown), MixState(state: .isOff)]
}

struct MixState: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var state: MixStateEnum
}

enum MixStateEnum: String {
    case isOn, isOff, isUnknown
}

EDIT-1:
This example code seems to work for me on MacOS.
Still using the same approach with @Bindable var model = model
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        MyView()
            .environment(model)
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @Environment(Model.self) private var model

    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var model = model
        VStack (spacing: 33) {
            Toggle("Test", sources: $model.modelStates, isOn: \.isOn)
                .onChange(of: model.modelStates) {
                    // just to do something on change
                    print("----> onChange: \n \(model.modelStates)")
                }
            // for testing, external change
            Button("Uncheck [0]") {
                model.modelStates[0].isOn = false
            }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
    }
}

@Observable class Model {
    var modelStates = [MixState(isOn: true), MixState(isOn: false)]
}

struct MixState: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var isOn: Bool
}


Maybe you are thinking of IOS? On MacOS there is definitely a mixed state checkbox and the documents clearly state the correct way to do it with SwiftUI is with an array of values. Furthermore my code does work as I stated. It just won't switch off again, but it does go from 'mixed' to 'on': https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toggle/init(_:sources:ison:)-3i05p

yes, I assumed for iOS, not MacOS, since it was not mentioned. I have not seen a 3 states Toggle on mac, I'll investigate.

updated my answer (EDIT-1) using Toggle(...) on MacOS.

Thanks - but that won't work in my case. In my original post I showed that I used a getter and setter on the toggle because I need to do some extra steps  and provide a filtered array of items, which can change dynamically.
